# real_escape_string sanitizing without mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysqli

Assume that I do not have a database running.  so I do not have a connection.  I would still like to sanitize web user input that will be written as sql statement into a file, and perhaps later sent onto some sql server.  is there a connection-free method to do this?

Comment: Find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437464/sanitize-contact-form-without-mysql-real-escape-string). In short, filter_var()

Comment: You could just do the insert later using parameterized queries..

Comment: Reasoning why this is not available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435232/using-mysqlis-real-escape-string-as-a-static-function

Comment: What is the purpose to sanitise data that is written to a **file**? A file can store anything without any sanitising.

Comment: @mseifert that answer is useless.